# Separating uppercase and lowercase characters in a string

Tags: r, string

I have data that looks like "TAGCAGaaccgtaAGTCAAgcgta" that I would like to split by the divide between upper and lowercase characters. So my output would be a list of uppercase strings "TAGCAG" and "AGTCAA" and lowercase strings "aaccgta" and "gcgta"

I have tried

```
str <- c("TAGCAGaaccgtaAGTCAAgcgta")
library(stringr)
str_extract(str, '[[:lower:]]+')
str_extract(str, '[[:upper:]]+')
```

but this only gives me the first instance of uppercase or lowercase. I would like to be able to get all of the instances in a list or dataframe of each.

Comment: Do you just need `str_extract_all` instead of `str_extract`?

Answer (score 3):

### Extract into separate vectors:

Like @Calum You said, `str_extract_all` returns all instance of the matched pattern:

```
str_extract_all(str, '[[:lower:]]+')
[1]]
[1] "aaccgta" "gcgta"  

str_extract_all(str, '[[:upper:]]+')
[[1]]
[1] "TAGCAG" "AGTCAA"
```

### Extract in one vector:

Or you can use the `|` regex to subset for both upper and lower case strings at the same time.

```
str_extract_all(str, '[[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]]+')
[[1]]
[1] "TAGCAG"  "aaccgta" "AGTCAA"  "gcgta"
```

You can `unlist()` the output to return vectors.

Answer (score 1):

In base, we can do this by combining `gregexpr()` with `regmatches()`:

```
m <- gregexpr("[[:upper:]]+|[[:lower:]]+", str)

regmatches(str, m)
```

Console:

```
[[1]]
[1] "TAGCAG"  "aaccgta" "AGTCAA"  "gcgta"
```